Get list of missing object keys when compared to master list
I have an "required" list of headers in an array that I am wanting to check an object of headers against.
My aim is to get a list of the headers that are missing.
I am wanting this to be case-insensitive.
// For example:

const masterHeads = ['head1', 'head2', 'Head3'];
const headers = {
  Heasd1: 'xxx',
  Head2: 'yyy',
  Head3: 'zzz',
  other: 'blah'
};

// output: [ head1 ]

I have so far devised
masterHeads.filter(master => !headers?.[master.toLowerCase()]);

but this seems to be case-sensitive.

Why not use an actual Headers? That has a case-insensitive has method. Or in the general case see dupe.

Start with new Set(Object.keys(headers).map(key => key.toLowerCase())).

Your master list seems to be inconsistent case-wise; I would start by making that consistent for easier comparison.

UPDATE: This isn't the answer but is perhaps a step to finding it...
This does the filtering to find which header(s) are missing, but returns them in lowercase and not in their original case.

I believe I found the answer after thinking about it for a bit longer.
I essentially map each array of the accepted and the header keys to lowercase entirely, then do a check to see if the headers includes the master headers
const lowerHeads = Object.keys(headers).map(head => head.toLowerCase());
const master = masterHeads.map(head => head.toLowerCase());
const res = master.filter(m => !lowerHeads.includes(m));

