What are the advantages of using Headers object instead of just using object literals when using fetch?
When setting request headers while using the fetch API, I can just use object literals or use a Headers object:

You can pass an object literal here containing header-name: header-value properties:
const response = await fetch("https://example.org/post", {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  // .,.
});

Alternatively, you can construct a Headers object, add headers to
that object using Headers.append(), then assign the Headers object
to the headers option:
const myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

const response = await fetch("https://example.org/post", {
  headers: myHeaders,
  // .,.
});


I checked the Headers documentation but I can't find the advantages of using it. So why bother?

Well the Headers class has methods to interrogate and manipulate the set of headers. Maybe that's useful sometimes.

And those methods handle case appropriately (example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78807894/get-list-of-missing-object-keys-when-compared-to-master-list#comment138944672_78807894). Or you might already have a headers object, in which case why change it back to a vanilla one. But as in all such cases, you don't have to use every option an API exposes - if the vanilla object works for your use case, use it.

@jonrsharpe After thinking about it again I think one use case maybe when I get a response, I can retrieve the header from it and check the header values. I still think it is a valid question, not an opinion-based one.

TypeScript fan here. It is very useful to us.

@ChukwujiobiCanon can you give some specific example ?

@Qiulang but that's not related to your choice of whether to pass a vanilla object or Headers to fetch; a Response always exposes a Headers object, regardless of how the request was constructed: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/headers

@jonrsharpe my question used request as an example but the question is really about headers and its usage.

You're welcome to try and [edit] to clarify, but the documentation you're quoting is specifically about the choice of input, and as I pointed out above you don't get a choice elsewhere.

If you're just passing one more or less hardcoded header object to the fetch function, then it hardly matters. If you want to programmatically manipulate headers before making the request, dynamically adding, removing, altering headers, perhaps from different components all with different capitalisation conventions, then it's useful.

@deceze when my question was down-voted then closed and google can't give me an answer I opened an issue against MDN, some member responded with the words somewhat like you said (I added my answer according to that).  BTW, I still believe my question is not an opinion based one and folks here sometime just rush to the conclusion.

I opened an issue against MDN document, asking to them to add some explanation for that. I got a response, to quote,

AFAIK it doesn't solve any problem that you can't solve with object
literals. Set-Cookie is an odd header that Headers handles specially
but you can't use that in fetch anyway. I think the only reason is for
convenience: for example if you already have a Headers from elsewhere
for whatever reason, or if you just like the Headers map-like API over
dynamically modifying an object when building a request.

